# Why my css for react-boostrap button didn't work?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hi guys so I'm trying to use css for my custom react-boostrap button but it didn't work. It show different result from what I want, anyone know why ?

[image: It Show different result from the css]

And this is my code:

```
            <Container fluid>
                <Row className="Aboutus fontReg">
                    <Col sm={12} lg={6}>
                        <Button variant="custom" as={Link} to={"/Room"}>
                            See Room
                        </Button>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
```

The CSS:

```
.btn-custom{
    font-size: 21px;
    background-color: #10255A;
    padding: 8px 25px 8px 25px;
    color:white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Can you include a working example with the output HTML? (You can use the browser Inspector or Developer tools to see what the actual output HTML is. In Chrome on Windows it's pressing `F12`.)

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: You could also add an explicit class name to the button using `className` right? Then you're always sure it has that class name :)

Comment: I have try that method but it didn't overwrite the default theming from boostrap (the button color stays blue)

Comment: If the class name on the button is the one you use in the CSS, it could be a specificity issue. The more specific a CSS selector is, the more priority it is given. [Read about CSS specificity here.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp)

Comment: I manage to solve the problem by adding the style inline not on separated css

Comment: It's good practice to keep your styling separate from the HTML. But anyway :) If it works, you can remove your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the class directly to your button. As said here above by Philipp: the more specific, the better.

Your button code should look like that :

```
<Button className="btn-custom> </Button>
```

You can of course keep your other attributes (link, to, any other)

Note that the capitalisation is important on the **className** attribute.